# Android studio try-catch suggestion for my method

Tags: android, android-studio

I build my own library in Android and i want to give a warning about try-catch block when my method use

For example my library class like below

```
public class MyLib{
    public void foo(){
        // any code here
    }
}
```

and the user's activity

```
MyLib lib = new MyLib();
lib.foo();
```

i want to here give a warning and after when the user press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> like below

```
MyLib lib = new MyLib();

try{
    lib.foo();
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

is there code, annotation or configration about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the IDE warns you about the unhandled exception, it means that the method throws a checked exception. This is what it should look like if your method throws an `IOException`:

```
public void foo() throws IOException {
}
```

Read more about checked exceptions [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Checked_Exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer was quite help

Answer (score 1):

Assume your method throws `JSONException`, add it to your method signature

```
public class MyLib{
    public void foo() throws JSONException{
        // any code here
    }
}
```

Now whichever class would try to access your code has to catch or throw this exception.

Comment: `IllegalStateException` is an unchecked exception, and the compiler won't warn you about not handling it.

Comment: It was an example, however thanks for suggestion updating my answer.